# Getting screen size in windows console project

Tags: vb.net

I have a vb.net console project that starts a number of applications and moves and resizes them to where I want on a double monitor set up (win 7)

All works great other than I cant seem to be able to get the available screen size. My intention is , if I know the screen area is 1000 pix wide then id size my applications to 1/3 of it and fit three in.

Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds 
Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea

states that screen is not declared. I scoured the internet and whilst there are a few solutions for a forms project I can't find anything for a console project...
Thanks

Comment: I have just tried using `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds` and `Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea`, they worked perfect. I had to add `Imports System.Windows.Forms` at the top for it to work.

Comment: I included the system.windows.forms import at the top of my module but it still complains about Screen
Error BC30451 'Screen' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. ve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a simple project to demonstrate how to get the screen size in a [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) console application.
Code I used is the next:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Module GetScreenSize

    Sub Main()
        Dim rectangle  = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
        Dim workingArea  = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea

        Console.WriteLine("Bounds: Height: " & rectangle.Height & ", Width: " & rectangle.Width)
        Console.WriteLine("WorkingArea: Height: " & workingArea.Height & ", Width: " & workingArea.Width)

        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

End Module
```

As Vincent mentioned in his comment, you need to add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` as well since it's not referenced by default in a Console application. Here's a picture of what my references in the project are:

[image: Project References]

My output was the next:

> Bounds: Height: 1080, Width: 1920
>   WorkingArea: Height: 1040, Width: 1920

In order to provide you with more help, I uploaded my solution to [my GitHub repo](https://github.com/tiger4589/Vb.Net.Console.ScreenSize)

Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Great thanks. yes I had missed the add the reference thing and read it as import which obviously didn't do the trick. I'm relatively new to visual studios and no expert in vb.net either.  so maybe you could help me to see your code.. I downloaded your project from the repository. When I open the project it doesn't show me any code ie the center pane of visual studios is blank. I know I probably have to click on something to show the code but can't find it...sorry for  newbyness...

Comment: You just need to open `ConsoleScreenSize.sln` and everything should show up.

Comment: I found it in solutions explorer at t he bottom. I'd done something that made my own source code disappear as well .

Comment: Thanks Paul your code (and now mine) works perfect. I also had to add the system.drawing reference (as shown in your list above) and the final piece of the puzzle click in to place. I don't know if I would have ever found this without your help so once again thanks dude..

Comment: No problem, this is what Stackoverflow is here for. Good luck with the rest of your task.

Comment: this gives me the dimensions of one screen but as I have two screens (in extend mode) is there a way to get the complete usable area or can I simply do the same thing for both then add the returned widths ?

Comment: According to [Microsoft Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) You can find all screens using `AllScreens`, then you can loop over them. Check the example in this documentation, it should suits you well.

Comment: Sub GetDeskTopSize()

        For Each screen In System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens

            Console.WriteLine("Working Area: " + screen.WorkingArea.ToString())

        Next
        Console.ReadKey()

    End Sub

Comment: Yep you are right again. it gives me everything i need to work out what the various screen widths are and where their top x an y positions are so this would work if i have one two or six screens . Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help. "Main" below is the name of the main form.

```
' center the form in the center of the users screen
 ' -------------------------------------------------
   Dim r As Rectangle
   If Main.Parent IsNot Nothing Then
     r = Main.Parent.RectangleToScreen(Main.Parent.ClientRectangle)
   Else
     r = Screen.FromPoint(Main.Location).WorkingArea
   End If

   Dim x = r.Left + (r.Width - Main.Width) \ 2
   Dim y = r.Top + (r.Height - Main.Height) \ 2
   Main.Location = New Point(x, y)
```

Comment: He's using a _**console application**_, why are you using forms?

Comment: Just putting it out there for his information. Maybe it can help in some way. It never hurts to have more knowledge.

Comment: But it is not related to his question. Answers should attempt to _**answer the question**_, not give helpful hints that are only partially (or not at all) related to the OP's question. That's what forums are for, this is a Q&A (Question and Answer) site. It should just be a question and an answer - plain and simple.

Comment: The problem is that the OP cannot even access the `Screen` class. That is what needs to be answered. -- Sorry for being so harsh, but this is how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: @VisualVincent But it is accessible from a console application.

Comment: @PaulKaram : Maybe for you, but not for the OP. That's what he's looking for an answer to. Your comment should rather be posted as an answer, because he's missing (like you say) the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace. Just remember to include adding a reference to the DLL as well, because that isn't referenced in console applications by default.

Comment: @VisualVincent Oh okay, I thought you were saying that it's not accessible at all, well, I just created a new console and imported and commented on the original post about my try. Waiting his reply.

Comment: Thanks for your effort user2721815 unfortunately I can't get this to work with a console project.

Comment: @Paul Karam and Vincent  what would I have to import to get the above code to work in a console project ?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the size in characters and pixels:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Module Module1
    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
    Public Structure RECT
        Public Left As Integer
        Public Top As Integer
        Public Right As Integer
        Public Bottom As Integer
    End Structure

    <DllImport("user32.dll")>
    Private Function GetWindowRect(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByRef lpRect As RECT) As Boolean
    End Function


    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Width: {0}", Console.WindowWidth))
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Height: {0}", Console.WindowHeight))


        Dim hWnd = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle
        Dim r As RECT

        If GetWindowRect(hWnd, r) Then
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Width: {0}", r.Right - r.Left))
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Height: {0}", r.Bottom - r.Top))
        End If
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: The OP wanted _**the screen size**_, not the size of the console window...

Comment: Thanks for the efforts in answering my problem. Dummy your answer works great for the console window but unfortunately it is the complete screen dimensions i need so that I can divide up my applications to fit the screen exactly..